# How do I use SUMIFS when the criteria ranges include both rows and columns?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to write a formula using the SUMIFS function where `criteria_range1` and `criteria_range2` are columns, but `criteria_range3` is a row.

For example, in the sample data below,

1. `criteria_range1` is the `"Field1"` **column** , `A2:A10`
2. `criteria_range2` is the `"Field2"` **column** , `B2:B10`
3. `criteria_range3` is the date **row** , `C1:H1`

In a separate sheet, I want to specify values for each of `criteria1 → criteria3` and I want SUMIFS to add the values that meet the criteria.

In my example SUMIFS should return `163` because `D2 (79)` and `D5 (84)` meet the criteria.

How do I write the formula?

###### Sample Data

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Field1** | **Field2** | **12/03/2020** | **`21/03/2020`** | **17/03/2020** | **22/03/2020** | **27/03/2020** | **25/03/2020** |
| **2** | `2_testval_field1` | `C_testval.field2` | 17 | `79` | 69 | 79 | 74 | 35 |
| **3** | 5_testval_field1 | E_testval.field2 | 78 | 10 | 57 | 46 | 91 | 59 |
| **4** | 1_testval_field1 | A_testval.field2 | 89 | 41 | 25 | 92 | 98 | 53 |
| **5** | `2_testval_field1` | `C_testval.field2` | 91 | `84` | 62 | 82 | 37 | 99 |
| **6** | 4_testval_field1 | D_testval.field2 | 72 | 65 | 21 | 97 | 100 | 71 |
| **7** | 6_testval_field1 | `C_testval.field2` | 84 | 50 | 68 | 59 | 14 | 45 |
| **8** | `2_testval_field1` | B_testval.field2 | 40 | 17 | 86 | 30 | 17 | 69 |
| **9** | 3_testval_field1 | `C_testval.field2` | 74 | 18 | 62 | 41 | 14 | 23 |
| **10** | `2_testval_field1` | G_testval.field2 | 30 | 12 | 53 | 25 | 22 | 26 |

###### Sample Results

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Range** | **Criteria** |  | **Function** | **Result** |
| **2** | Field1 | `2_testval_field1` |  | SUMIFS | `163` |
| **3** | Field2 | `C_testval.field2` |  |  |  |
| **4** | Date | `21/03/2020` |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

This approach first uses FILTER to return only those rows where both `Field1` and `Field2`  match the lookup values in `B2` and `B3`.

It then uses INDEX and MATCH to return the column that matches the lookup date in `B4`, and then SUM to add the values in that column.

IFERROR is added for cases where either FILTER or MATCH don't return anything.

The following formula can be placed in `E2`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(
   FILTER(data!A:H, data!A:A=B2, data!B:B=B3),,
   MATCH(B4, data!1:1, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i misunderstood the task. So following formula returns sum from table only if Field1, Field2 and Date are matched

```
=iferror(QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet8!A:A&Sheet8!B:B),Sheet8!C:E},
"select Col"&MATCH($B$1,Sheet8!$C$1:$E$1,0)+1&" where Col1 = '"&A2&B2&"'"),"no matches")
```

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19YYOQ6XvvYzukZFlbR8wG7pGn9wstxHLR6rMAOX8LaA/edit#gid=83729257)